# TextArea character limit how to set?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

I have one css+jscript form where text area is set, I want to set the limit within for lets say only 50 characters.

```
"CSV": {     
"Name": "CSVData",     
"Title": "Provide machines data:",     
"Description": "Enter Machine Names",     
"UIType": "textArea",      
"Default": "", "Required":"1"},
```

What should I add along with **"UIType": "textArea"** so that defined text area will only accept 50 characters.

Comment: JScript was a ECMAScript variant created by Microsoft in the 1990s, its last appearance was in Internet Explorer 9. Do you mean JavaScript? Also, what framework are you using? Because we have no idea how that code affects the HTML produced.

Comment: How does `"UIType": "textArea"` (and the rest of your configuration) get translated/converted to *actual* HTML?

Answer (score 0):

***Edited***

In your HTML you can use the maxlength attribute.

```
<textarea maxlength = "50" name = "description">
            Enter answer here...
</textarea>
```

Thanks Heretic Monkey for the clarification on the bugs of the maxlength attribute.

Here is an **alternate solution** with a working demo:

```js
function maxLength(el) {    
    if (!('maxLength' in el)) {
        var max = el.attributes.maxLength.value;
        el.onkeypress = function () {
            if (this.value.length >= max) return false;
        };
    }
}

maxLength(document.getElementById("text"));
```

```html
<textarea maxlength="50" id="text"></textarea>
```

Comment: `maxlength` has a sordid history when used on a `textarea` and continues to have bugs on some mobile browsers. See the duplicate and [caniuse's chart](https://caniuse.com/maxlength) for more details.